# Java Formatting

Tags: java, format

I am trying to format a string whereby the '$' stick close to the price.

For example:

```
Oranges     3     $3.00     $9.00
```

But what I currently have:

```
Oranges     3 $    3.00 $    9.00
```

This is my code: (Note: "price" and "total" are double datatype)

```
System.out.printf("%-25s %10s $%10s $%10s", item, quantity, price, total);
```

I want to have a gap in between every output but I can't find a way to get the result
that I wanted. Is there any ways to solve this?

Comment: I'd recommend using [Java's Locale dependent formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html), than making your own.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
System.out.printf("%-25s %10s %10s %10s", item, quantity, "$" + price, "$" + total);
```

output

```
Oranges                            3       $3.0       $9.0
```

or, best of all, use a formatter method

```
    String format(double d) {
        return String.format("$%.2f", d);
    }
...
    System.out.printf("%-25s %10s %10s %10s", item, quantity, format(price), format(total));
```

output

```
Oranges                            3      $3.00      $9.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the 10 space padding on the price and the total.

```
System.out.printf("%-25s %10s $%s $%s", item, quantity, price, total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just convert them to a String for output? The Double type can have the toString() method called on it, as per this link:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Convertdoubletostring.htm

And then you can just output a dollar symbol at the top of each string (you could even loop through all the strings if you load them into an array, and add a dollar symbol to all of them).

This might not be the best option, but I'm sure it'll work.